# Is any sort of "Public Domain Mark" required when using public domain content?

Tags: public-domain

Say I wanted to use a painting from the public domain for a book cover. Is it necessary to apply any sort of "public domain mark"?  If so, does it need to appear in a particular place (e.g., the cover itself vs. a copyright page)?

The reason I'm attempting to do so is because commons.wikimedia.org has stated that one 'must also include a United States public domain tag to indicate why this work is in the public domain in the United States.'

Comment: Can you give a link to the Wikimedia Commons page where you saw this?  I very much doubt there is any legal requirement for such a mark; the whole point of public domain is that there are no legal restrictions or conditions on how you can copy it.  I suspect you may be looking at something that's just a policy for the Wikimedia Commons website itself, saying how they want to label material on their site; but it wouldn't apply to uses of the material anywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

If a work is in the public domain, then there are no particular requirements on its use; in particular, it can be used on a book cover without a copyright notice, a public domain notice, or any other kind of notice or mark.

[Wikimedia Commons' public domain template](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:PD-Art&oldid=358286489) says, "You must also include a United States public domain tag to indicate why this work is in the public domain in the United States." This is a notice to users of Wikimedia Commons, informing them that if they upload a public domain image *to Wikimedia Commons*, they must include a public domain tag. That's a policy of Wikimedia Commons. It doesn't apply to people using the image outside of Wikimedia.